# Best way to capture page URL for quiz results page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Imagine taking a quiz at mysite/test/universe (URL = 'universe') or mysite/test/earth (URL = 'earth'). After you select the answers and click the Submit button, you're forwarded to a static page at mysite/test/results.php. The form automatically forwards some test data (e.g. $answer1 = $_POST['q1']).

Is there a way to modify the script so that, when someone clicks the Submit button, the page's URL is also captured and forwarded to the results page?

I don't want the URL itself to change. For example, if people are forwarded to mysite/test/results%universe, or something like that, then they could just visit that URL to see all the answers.

So I just want to forward the value of the URL, which I can then use to display and style correct and incorrect answers, along with feedback.

I should also explain that I'm working with PHP, jQuery and perhaps AJAX, and my ultimate goal is to modify my tests so that users can log in, and the test results will be published to a database. With that in mind, what's the best way to modify the HTML below so that the page URL is captured and forwarded to the results page?

```
<div id="quiz" rel="key" style="width: 500px; margin: 10px auto;">
  <form action="grade.php" method="post" id="quiz">
    <ol>
      <li id="q1">
        <div class="Question">No one knows if there&#8217;s just one universe or a series of universes, sometimes referred to as a:</div>
        <div class="Answer">
          <label for="q1-A"><div class="Radio"><input type="radio" name="q1" id="q1-A" value="A" style="display: none;"> A. multiverse</div></label></div>
        <div class="Answer">
          <label for="q1-B"><div class="Radio"><input type="radio" name="q1" id="q1-B" value="B" style="display: none;"> B. parallel universe</div></label></div>
      </li>
    </ol>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit Quiz" />
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a hidden field in your form

`<input type="hidden" id="url" />`

and set its value with this javascript

`document.getElementById("url").value = document.URL;`

or this jQuery

`$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input#url").attr("value", $(location).attr('href'));
});`

then it will be submitted with the form.

Comment: Thanks; that looks pretty simple, though I'm a little confused. I'm supposed to have TWO inputs, one that the user clicks to get forwarded to the results page, plus a hidden input, right? Then I add the new JavaScript after the form closing tag. I typed echo $url; on the results page, but when I click the submit button, it doesn't echo a value. Did I do something wrong, or am I just missing an extra step?

<input type="submit" value="Submit Quiz" />
<input type="hidden" id="url" />
</form>

<script>
document.getElementById("url").value = document.URL;
</script>

Comment: Two inputs, yes; the submit button and the new hidden input. I think echo $url is php, which I'm not familiar with. The new hidden input containing the url will be available wherever the form is posted to. Presumably, you will read this with php, but I can't help with that.

Comment: Look at this http://jsfiddle.net/88ghma8a/ and examine the Submit button in the developer tools (right click Submit button and select  "Inspect element' in Chrome). Just above HTML for the Submit button you will see `<input type="hidden" id="url" value="http://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/">`. This is the hidden input containing the url.

Comment: @ Mark Wade - Now I understand. Do you know how to display the captured value on the results page with JavaScript? It isn't working for me, but that's probably because I don't know how to display the value, and I'm not sure if it's returning /test/gw-intro-1, test/gw-intro-1 or gw-intro-1.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't directly access posted values from javascript. However, they should be available to your php. You could then use php to make them available to javascript. I recommend getting really familiar with the developer toolbar available in popular browsers (F12) so you can see behind the scenes. Absolutely indispensable tool for web devs. You'll wonder how you ever managed without it. I know I did.

Answer (score 0):

you can use query string. if your first page url in http://something.html and second page url after form submit is another.html then

```
 <form action="another.html?previous=<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>">
 </form>
```

In another.html, you can get previous  page url before submitting form by using GET

```
 $_GET["previous"]
```